# How to refresh the main view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have in my activity 3 fragments which each is numbered like 1,2 & 3. It's kind like a step activity ; if fragment 1 is done, the view content concerned will be replaced by the second fragment and it is the same for frgs. 2 & 3.

I have in the possibility in my action bar to change the app. language and when I change it I need to refresh the concerned layout with the new ressources and for that I use :

```
   private fun refreshView() {
        this.recreate()
   }
```

My pb. is when the activity is recreated and I'm in the second or the third fragment, the activity is returned to the first one.

How should I fix this ? and is there a solution to refresh the view without recreating the activity ?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a static Constants class or in application class where you can save the current fragment as count or string, and after recreate show the Fragment you saved in the above mentions class.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the fragment number in SharedPreference. But recreating the activity is the wrong approach in my opinion. You should just reload all the data in the current fragment instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to see this documentation that explain how to save UI state: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

In my opinion ViewModel can be a good choice for your problem, coupled with LiveData.

ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

LiveData: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int fragmentIndex = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragmentIndex++;
            if (fragmentIndex >= 3) {
                fragmentIndex = 0;
            }
            showFragment(fragmentIndex);
        }
    });
    //get the index saved
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragmentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("index");
    }
    showFragment(fragmentIndex);
}

//override this function to save fragment index. This function will be called when activity is destroyed.
//And when activity is recreated, you can get the index from the savedInstanceState as code above.
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("index", fragmentIndex);
}



private void showFragment(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = SimpleFragment.createFragment(String.valueOf(index));
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}

public static class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
    public static SimpleFragment createFragment(String index) {
        SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("index", index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, container, false);
        TextView indexView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_index);
        String index = getArguments().getString("index");
        indexView.setText(index);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

You can test my code with or without overriding the `onSaveInstanceState` function by rotating device witch makes activity recreate